# List of properties

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Is there a way to make a list of class properties? For example, I have a WPF project with TextBoxes bound to string properties as such: (yes the actual version does implement INotifyPropertyChanged...)

```
private string lName;
public string LName {
    get { return lName; }
    set { lName = value; }
}
```

and I want to make a List that contains all of these properties (so I could do things like set them all to empty strings in a for loop). My guess was unsafe pointers like

```
unsafe {
    List<String*> myProps = new List<string*>()
    myProps.Add(&lastName);
}
```

but that gives me *"Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('string')"*

and doing it for **int** properties List<**Int32***> yields *"You can only take the address of an unfixed expression inside a fixed statement initializer"*

Comment: I'd use Reflection for this. GetType().GetProperties() and SetValue() for each one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use Reflection. If you only want the [public properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x(v=vs.110).aspx), you will just need to do something similar to the following:

```
var type = typeof(MyClass);

foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties.Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string))) {
     // do stuff
}
```

If you want private (or other class variables) there are overloads for the [`GetFields()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ztex2dc(v=vs.110).aspx) method still on the `type` variable outlined above.